# Opening an image using 'system' or 'exec'

Tags: ruby, windows

My goal is to open image files in a default image viewer (Windows 10 Photos app), and close them per user input. My file path contains backslashes, not standard slashes, although replacing them doesn't seem to change the results I mention below.

I tried the following:

```
Kernel.system('full_path_to_image')
```

or the same thing using `exec` instead, but it simply returns a format error `Errno::ENOEXEC`. Manually entering the file path in the command interpreter works even if the interpreter is opened via:

```
Kernel.system('cmd')
```

I tried to avoid the shell by using a multi-argument version of `system`, but I could not.

Is it possible to do what I want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/246827/102368), this should work on windows.

```
system("start #{path_to_image}")
```